# Measuring voltage across short circuit

Tags: voltage, electricity

Assume a simple short circuit with the probes on a multimeter at any point along the circuit:

[image]

Can we assume that the voltage read will be 0v, as all points along the wire have the same voltage?

If we then add a resistor:

[image]

And measure the voltage across the resistor, at which resistance would you register 5v?

How does Ohm's law verify this?

Answer (score 4):

> Assume a simple short circuit with the probes on a multimeter at any point along the circuit:

OK, but the 5 V supply will have to go into current limit. You can't have 5 V **and** a short circuit.

> Can we assume that the voltage read will be 0 V, as all points along the wire have the same voltage?

Yes.

> If we then add a resistor and measure the voltage across the resistor, at which resistance would you register 5 V?

It depends on the current capability of the power supply. For example, if it can supply 2 A at 5 V then ...

> How does Ohm's law verify this?

... \$ R = \frac {V}{I}  = \frac {5}{2} = 2.5 \ \Omega \$ and that's the minimum circuit resistance that the PSU can drive while maintaining 5 V.

It always works.

---

Notes:

When you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar the editable schematics are saved in line with your question. No account needed. No screengrabs or upload needed.

Electrical unit symbols named after a person are capitalised in symbol form and are lowercase when spelled out. So, 'V' for volt, 'A' for ampere, 'W' for watt, 'K' for kelvin (whereas small 'k' is for kilo) and a capital \$ \Omega \$ for ohm.

---

> What's confusing me is how the pin at GND suddenly reads 0, even as the resistance > 2.5 increases? Why wouldn't it read it with a lower resistance, even if the circuit was "demanding" more current than the PSU could handle?

GND in a circuit is just a reference point. You can think of it as where we would normally connect the black lead of the multimeter which is switched to V DC. Since the wire in question is thick and made of a good conductor then all points along the wire will be at ground potential when measured with the red probe of the meter. In a real circuit with current you would get an increasing millivolt reading the further you move the red from the black lead.

[image]

*Figure 1. A rheostat. Note the wound resistance wire and the exposed strip with the movable contact. Source: [Resistor Guide](http://www.resistorguide.com/rheostat/).*

Now if we add in the resistor the situation changes. The current is reduced and if we were able to touch the red probe at various points along the resistor we would see the voltage rise to 1 V at 20% up from the bottom, 2 V at 40%, etc. until we reached the top and we would measure 5 V. We could use the rheostat in the photo by connecting one end to +5 V and the other to GND. Then connect the red probe to the wiper and move it along.

> Really, what I'm asking is, if current is the same throughout the circuit, how does one pin know it is upwards of the resistor, and therefore read 5 V, and the other downwards, and read 0 V. I ask this in theory and practise.

The pin doesn't know but the voltmeter can measure it. The potential difference with GND is decreasing as we move down along the resistor.

Comment: How about in a theoretical circuit, with no maximum current capability?

Comment: Sorry, I live in the real world. There is always a maximum current capability and a non-zero resistance (excepting super-conductors which I don't have in my garage).

Comment: So, as per your example, measuring across a resistor with > 2.5ohms will give you 5v?

Comment: Yes, as stated: "*= 2.5 Ω  and that's the minimum circuit resistance that the PSU can drive while maintaining 5 V.*"

Comment: @B4039 Your language is confusing, but I think what you need to study is the "passive sign convention". Also, note that the voltage source and resistor are in series (same current) but also in parallel (same voltage).

Comment: @B: See the update. Remember, 'V' for volt.

Comment: Even in the real world, where we both live, students must construct models that can be analyzed mathematically. Those models are built from ideal elements...wires and voltage sources have no resistance. These assumptions are usually made by circuit simulators as well. I think we should remember that when we get questions from people who are clearly students.

Comment: I know, thanks, Elliot, but I think I covered that in the first line of the answer. S/he can have 5 V or a 0 Ω short-circuit but not both.

Comment: You did say that you couldn't have a short circuit across a supply, but you said that the short circuit would win and the supply would be current limited, which isn't something that an ideal source would do.

Comment: @Elliot. OK. I won't argue. :^)

Answer (score 0):

> Can we assume that the voltage read will be 0v, as all points along
>   the wire have the same voltage?

Every wire has certain resistance "r1". It might be small, but finite. Therefore there is not such thing as "short".

If your supply has unlimited capability and infinitely small ESR (internal equivalent series resistor), you will still read 5V across your wire, which will carry huge current I=5/r1. If you try to measure any voltage across two arbitrary points along the short wire, your readings will be proportional to the selected length of "short" wire. The wire will serve as a simple "rheostat".

However, every voltage source has internal impedance, maybe small but still finite, say "r2". Then the "short wire" r1 and internal ESR r2 will form a voltage divider, and your measurement across the "short wire" will read a corresponding portion of 5V. And the flowing current will be 5/(r1+r2).

Comment: No, when learning about circuits we use **ideal** wires that have no resistance. It is true that **real** wires **typically** have a non-zero resistance but I think the OP is a student studying ideal circuits. Likewise, ideal voltage sources have no series resistance. We teach students that if the wire resistance and supply resistance are relevant then they must be added explicitly to the schematic. Unfortunately, students often concoct little circuits like this where the ideal circuit conflicts with real life observation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, "We teach students that if the wire resistance and supply resistance are relevant then they must be added explicitly to the schematic." - apparently in this case this teaching has fallen onto deaf ears... I am wondering though, how do you teach when these hidden resistances are relevant, and when not?

Comment: Yes, the OP does not seem to understand the limits of "ideal" models and that is a sad commentary on higher education. Mea culpa. It is hard to teach students when the parasitic resistances are relevant, and it seems that this wisdom comes from practice and experience. I wish I could teach this material more effectively. I try to work through as many examples as I can. Many students seem to come in without critical thinking skills, and that doesn't help.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, from your reply I tend to think that your entire teaching concept is flawed. You should start with physical wires and their resistance, and explain the Ohm's Law, then introduce "high-resistance" wires (frequently coiled), and then introduce a concept of "negligibly small resistance" on certain thick segments of resistive network, and thus introduce the concept of "ideal wire", the one where the voltage drop can be neglected. This would naturally explain when this voltage drop is relevant, and when it can be neglected. Physics rulez, sorry.

Comment: You are certainly entitled to your opinion about the educational process. It is what it is; I am not king of the world and I was not defending the educational system. I was trying to help the OP understand why the question was flawed.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, just to clarify, this is not something I was taught. Rather, I am teaching myself (or trying to) via online resources. Anyway, all is understood now; I just needed something to click in my brain, which it has now. :)

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, the difficulty with learning this stuff online is the lack of consistency between different sites, in terms of analogies, terminology, etc. used. One moment something makes perfect sense, then you move on to another site and read the same topic, and find it doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: So perhaps a little unfair to say that my confusion is a reflection on education standards, or a lack of critical thinking on my part... :)

Comment: @19172281, don't be too upset. If educators are confused with mathematics of lim r->0 and relevant implications, what should we expect from their students?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what that even is, so not sure if that was meant to be facetious or not. Hahaha

Comment: I think all my confusion could have been avoided if I had  bothered to learn/remember ohms law properly, and then it would have all worked out mathematically. So, my fault really.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are a student asking about **ideal** wires and **ideal** voltage sources, such as you would encounter when trying to construct a mathematical model of a circuit on paper or in a simulator.

An ideal wire has no resistance (or capacitance or inductance). So there is no voltage change between any two points on a given wire, regardless of how much current passes through it.

An ideal voltage source constrains the voltage between two points in a circuit, regardless of how much current flows or which direction it flows.

If you put an ideal wire between the two terminals of an ideal voltage source you get a nonsensical circuit. You have violated the definition of either the ideal wire or the ideal source, so such a circuit cannot be analyzed mathematically. It's as if you put an ideal voltage source of zero volts in parallel with an ideal voltage source of five volts...it is a nonsense circuit because it violates the basic definitions of ideal circuits.

Now, when you add a resistor then the voltage source and the resistor are in parallel so the voltage across them must be the same, and the voltage across the resistor must be positive at the top. Ohm's Law and the passive sign convention then tell you which direction the current flows.

Comment: "such a circuit cannot be analyzed mathematically." This is wrong. Mathematics has a nice technique of "limits", when a finite quantity tends to the limit of "infinitesimally small", or to "infinity" in opposite case. This offers a perfect tool to mathematically analyze singularities in oddly constructed circuits.

Comment: While Ali's comment is correct, division of zero is still undefined. Setting up a short corresponds to writing I = V / 0, which is undefined no matter how you apply limits to it.

Comment: @Pål-KristianEngstad, apparently I didn't explain well the mathematical ideas of limits, infinitesimally-small variables and asymptotic analysis in general.  Setting up a short should be expressed as I = V /( lim r1->0).

Comment: @AliChen If you say that there is a voltage across the wire then you have violated the definition of an ideal wire...the whole model breaks down. How did you decide that the ideal voltage source overrides an ideal wire, rather than the other way around? How do you know that the ideal wire didn't cause the voltage source to go to zero volts? You made an unjustified assumption and reached a conclusion that, I believe, is nonsense.

Comment: Elliot, if you re-read the OP question, there is no mentioning of "ideal wire" whatsoever. OPs mentioning "probes on a multimeter" hints to more pragmatic interpretation. So the "ideal wire" assumption is solely yours and not well justified either.

Comment: @AliChen I freely admitted that I was making an assumption, and I clearly based my answer on that assumption...something I think we should all do. Whether the assumption was justified is solely in the eyes of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

A 1mm diameter wire will have 20 microOhms resistance per millimeter (I computed this, using the resistance of 1 square of copper foil ---- 35 micron thick ---- is 0.000500 ohms, and stacked 28 of these layers to be 1mm thick, and then rounded the corners a bit).

Thus a short is never a short. You can add a booster to your DVM, and measure microVolts, thusly

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiGaiO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>